# Strange behavior of sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql

I have following table structure in my DB

```
ID               Name
--------------------------
ID_1             Name1

ID1              Name2
```

when I execute the following query

```
SELECT * FROM tblNames
WHERE ID LIKE '_1'
```

I get both records selected...

any suggestions how to get rid off it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An underscore (`_`) is a special character in LIKE expressions that matches a single character.

To match an actual underscore, you need to escape it:

```
select * from tblNames where id like '%\_1' escape '\'
```

Here I'm telling SQL Server to consider backslash an escape character, and using it to escape the underscore.

Alternatively, you can represent the underscore as a character range with a single character in it - it will be interpreted literally in this case:

```
select * from tblNames where id like '%[_]1'
```

Which is a bit more succinct.

Reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232(SQL.80).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[LIKE operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232(SQL.80).aspx)

Quickie: _ is a wildcard character that matches anything.

```
SELECT * FROM tblNames
WHERE ID LIKE '\_1' ESCAPE '\'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tblNames
WHERE ID LIKE '[_]1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The underscore character is a wildcard for the `like` operator, and it matches any one character. In your case the pattern '_1' matches both '_1' and 'D1' in the data.

To use a literal underscore character in a pattern you need to put brackets around it so that it becomes a character range containing only one character:

```
SELECT * FROM tblNames
WHERE ID LIKE '[_]1'
```